# how to sort below NSMutableArray structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i want below array(10 elements) to be sorted ascending order of  
  **"/Users/bkothari/Library....Photo-0.png" to be 0th element** 
 
 of an array and so on

**I have tried to use**

```
NSArray *sorted = [profileImageArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

but its not working.

```
profileImageArray (
    "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-4.png",
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
   "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-1.png",
    "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-0.png"
)
```

**Final output required:**

```
  profileImageArray (
    "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-0.png",
     "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-1.png",
    1,
    1,
    "/Users/bkothari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/233D4F5D-CDB0-4D55-8037-5DD674558BB0/Documents/MyFolder/Photo-4.png",
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
)
```

Comment: What about those 1 elements in the array? They also seem to be ordered by a pattern.

Comment: have you try with `NSNumericSearch` option?

Comment: No they are dummy text. only paths must be sorted and dummy elements must be rearranged accordingly

Comment: I guess you want to sort data according to `Photo-0.png, Photo-1.png, Photo-2.png` ?

Comment: @bhavyakothari: Have you check my answer?

Comment: @Virussmca - yes i have tested your answer its working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with **sortedArrayUsingComparator** using `NSNumericSearch` option

try this:

```
profileImageArray = [profileImageArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```